Traefik: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I switched now successful to the production letsencryt server and get all the time these errors:
2024-07-12T17:22:38Z DBG github.com/traefik/traefik/v3/pkg/tls/tlsmanager.go:228 > Serving default certificate for request: "cloudmedia4.tubebg.com"
2024-07-12T17:22:38Z DBG log/log.go:245 > http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.0.1:50396: remote error: tls: bad certificate

The certificates for example.com and traefik.example.com are fine when I check inside the browser. What is this causing?
My docker-compose.yaml:
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v3.0"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--ping=true"
      - "--api=true"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--api.dashboard=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--providers.docker.endpoint=tcp://dockerproxy:2375"
      - "--providers.docker.network=paperless_external"
      - "--entryPoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entryPoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
      - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.email=${EMAIL}"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
      #- "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencrypt.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule: Host(`traefik.${DOMAIN}`)
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints: websecure
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service: api@internal
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls: true
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver: letsencrypt
      traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares: dashboard-auth
      traefik.http.middlewares.dashboard-auth.basicauth.users: "${TRAEFIK_USER}:${TRAEFIK_PASSWORD_HASH}"
      traefik.http.middlewares.dashboard-auth.basicauth.removeheader: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/mnt/documents/letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges=true
    healthcheck:
      # Run traefik healthcheck command
      # https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/operations/cli/#healthcheck
      test: [ "CMD", "traefik", "healthcheck", "--ping" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 5s
    networks:
      - external

  webserver:
    image: ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx-image:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - gotenberg
      - tika
    volumes:
      - /mnt/documents/data:/usr/src/paperless/data
      - /mnt/documents/media:/usr/src/paperless/media
      - /mnt/documents/export:/usr/src/paperless/export
      - /mnt/documents/consume:/usr/src/paperless/consume
      - /mnt/documents/trash:/usr/src/paperless/trash
      - /mnt/documents/logs:/usr/src/paperless/logs
      - /mnt/documents/custom-cont-init.d:/custom-cont-init.d:ro
    env_file: docker-compose.env
    environment:
      PAPERLESS_REDIS: redis://broker:6379
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENABLED: 1
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_GOTENBERG_ENDPOINT: http://gotenberg:3000
      PAPERLESS_TIKA_ENDPOINT: http://tika:9998
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.service=paperless"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
      - "traefik.http.routers.paperless.middlewares=paperless-cors,paperless-workaround"
      - "traefik.http.services.paperless.loadbalancer.server.port=8000"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-cors.headers.accesscontrolallowmethods=*"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-cors.headers.accesscontrolallowheaders=*"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-cors.headers.accesscontrolalloworiginlist=${DOMAIN}"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-cors.headers.accesscontrolmaxage=100"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-cors.headers.addvaryheader=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.paperless-workaround.headers.customrequestheaders.authorization="
    networks:
      - internal
      - external


The log indicates that a request for "cloudmedia4.tubebg.com" was received and Traefik used a default certificate. A client/browser usually does not know and accept the default cert, then the error is shown in the log.
Note both lines are debug ("DBG") level only, not real errors.

It's a new server and I don't expect to receive something from anyone. cloudmedia4.tubebg.com is not my domain. How can I figure out who or what and why is happening?

You are on the Internet. You even use LetsEncrypt which has a public register for all created domain certs. You will receive unwanted requests all day long, that's just normal life.
